# CircleCI error when attempting to restore/save cache

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I'm configuring CircleCI to try and cache dependencies so I don't have to run `yarn install` on every single commit.

This is what my `config.yml` file looks like:

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build-and-test-frontend:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:14
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          name: Restore Yarn Package Cache
          keys:
            - yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
      - run:
          working_directory: ./frontend/tests
          name: Run jest tests
          command: |
            yarn install --frozen-lockfile --cache-folder ~/.
            yarn test
      - save_cache:
          name: Save Yarn Package Cache
          key: yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
          paths:
            - ~/.cache/yarn

workflows:
  sample:
    jobs:
      - build-and-test-frontend
```

But when either `restore_cache` or `save_cache` attempts to run, I get the following error:

```
error computing cache key: template: cacheKey:1:17: executing "cacheKey" at <checksum "yarn.lock">: error calling checksum: open /home/circleci/project/yarn.lock: no such file or directory
```

I'm brand new to using CircleCI so I'm not sure how to interpret this. What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

This is the structure of my directory:

```
--project_root
 |
 |--frontend
    |-node_modules/
    |-public/
    |-src/
    |-tests/
    |-package.json
    |-yarn.lock
```

Comment: The error suggest that you do not have a `yarn.lock` file in the root of your repository on GitHub/Bitbucket. Is that true?

Comment: strange because I do, in the root directory of the project (the same level as `frontend`). Could it be that I have to re-declare my `working_directory` for each `step`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard for me to give a great answer since I can't see your files in the repo but the config you have now suggest that the `yarn.lock` file you have is not in the root of the repo but rather in `./frontend/tests`.

If that's where it is and that's where you want to keep it, then I'd suggest moving the `working_dir` key from the step level to the job level. This will then apply it to every step including the caching steps. Then they should find the file they are looking for.

Update:

Thanks for the repo tree. According to that you likely want to have your config like this:

```
version: 2.1

workflows:
  sample:
    jobs:
      - build-and-test-frontend

jobs:
  build-and-test-frontend:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:14.17
    working_directory: ./frontend
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          name: Restore Yarn Package Cache
          keys:
            - yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
      - run:
          name: Run jest tests
          command: |
            yarn install --frozen-lockfile --cache-folder ~/.
            yarn test
      - save_cache:
          name: Save Yarn Package Cache
          key: yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
          paths:
            - ~/.cache/yarn
```

You'll notice a few things here:

1. I moved `workflows` to that top. That's just a personal stylistic choice but I believe it helps keep your config readable as it grows.
2. I moved `working_directory` to the job level instead of the step it was on.
3. I set `working_directory` to the frontend directory. Most filepaths on CircleCI will be relative to the working_directory. Since that's where `yarn.lock` is, that's where I set it.
4. I change the image from `circleci/node:14` to `cimg/node:14`. The images in the `circleci` namespaces are deprecated. Going forward, you'll want to use the newer CircleCI images which are in the `cimg` namespace.

Comment: Hi please see the recent edit I made with the project repo tree. I've tried moving the `working_directory` up to just above `steps` and just above `restore_cache` but neither worked.